# Epson WF-3620DWF turns off during startup

Tags: printing, printer, epson-workforce

I have an Epson WF-3620 and recently it couldn't print anything, as it sounded as if the paper was stuck, then the printer rolled the paper through and displayed an error on the screen, it told me to turn the printer off via the button and turn it back on again.

Now I am getting this issue where before the booting finishes and it takes me to the home screen, the printhead suddenly stops and the entire thing shuts down.

Its also always in this position when the entire thing shuts down

(The printhead is the grey box with colours inside)

[image: The printer]

How do I fix it then? Is the printhead dead, or do I need to find out how to do a factory reset

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do I fix this issue? I'll edit it

Comment: Is it possible this is the answer over here: http://superuser.com/questions/1153581/epson-wf-3520-printer-starts-up-and-then-shuts-down-repeatedly  I know it's a different model, but from Eric's response, it may be the same.

Answer (score -1):

I have an Epson WF3620 and experienced a similar issue.  I called Epson and it turns out there's a bug affecting these printers.  The issue is related to Epson's wifi and your router. There's no fix (yet) but you can get around it by following these steps.

1. unplug your router
2. unplug printer
3. Plug in printer
4. on the printer go to Settings/System Administration/Restore Default Setting/Clear All Data and Settings
5. plug in router
6. set up wifi using wifi wizard and everything should work

It can/will stop working again if your router restarts for any reason.  Folow these steps to get it working again.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently this is related to Google Cloud Print - at least in part. This issue came up TODAY and they are fielding MANY calls about it. He said Google is actively working on it, but I can find no reference to this on the Cloud Print site so I'm not 100% the problem isn't actually with Epson.

The above described steps are what I had to do, as guided by the Epson tech, and it did fix my issue. By having the router on, the printer tries to connect and encounters the issue. Turning it off severs that connection and allows the printer to boot properly. It also wipes out Google Cloud Print settings. The tech said if I re-register with Cloud Print before this widespread issue is resolved, it will bring back the failure to start issue.

I'm not sure how to find out status of the issue other than calling Epson Support with very long wait times tomorrow. If anyone else can provide an update here, or a link to Google showing this issue there, please do so.