# Epson WF-2540 cycles on and off

Tags: printer, epson-workforce

My Epson WF-2540 continuously cycles on and off, it runs a scan check while on. I have no Google cloud services turned on, no firmware updates have been made. Wireless can't be shut off. I have uninstalled it from the PC and re-installed using USB instead of wireless.

Comment: If you turn off the wireless router, does the printer stop power cycling?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Epson WorkForce printer keeps power-cycling](http://superuser.com/questions/1153581/epson-workforce-printer-keeps-power-cycling)

Answer (score 0):

My EPSON WF-7610 was in the off state when I got into my home office this morning.  I purposely leave my printer on continuously.  When I turned it on to print a document, I noticed it turned off on its own.  I did this several times and each time it powered off after attempting to run through its normal checks and internal motor cycling.  The printer is connected via a wireless network and does not have any wired communications connection.  This was very puzzling...

I jumped online and found a site that indicated to turn off my wireless network and then cycle power on the printer.  When I did it came up and stayed on as I would expect.  I did a print out of the printer settings including the wifi settings so I could reenter them after I did a factor default reset via the administrative settings.  I performed the reset, reentered my wifi settings.  Upon doing this the printer needed a nozzle cleaning which was missing many print lines in the black ink cartridge.  I don't know if this was a related problem or caused by some sort of a printer upgrade that occurred without my knowledge, but after a couple printer head/nozzle cleanings the printout test pattern was okay.  I powered up my wireless network and used the Printer WIFI connection configuration to reconnect my printer to my wifi network.  Once this was complete, the printer is functioning as normal.  I would have never thought turning off my wifi network would have fixed this but it sure did.  If there is a situation where you are unable to turnoff the wifi network because it is shared by others, contact the wifi admin group and have them "block" the specific wifi IP address of the suspect printer so it can no longer connect to the wifi network.  This should allow the printer to power up and allow the wifi to be disabled and a factory reset to be performed.... All the Best to those with this EPSON printer auto power down....

Comment: Thank you, I turned off the router then restarted the printer. The wifi did not turn on and the printer is remaining on. I am printing with a cable for now. Thank you for the help.